# How do I convert RFC822 to a python datetime object?

Tags: python, rfc822

I know how to do this the other way around... it would be:

```
>>> dt.rfc822()
'Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00 -0500'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
In [1]: import rfc822     # This only works for python 2 series

In [2]: rfc822.parsedate_tz('Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00 -0500')
Out[2]: (1997, 3, 9, 13, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0, -18000)
```

in python3 parsedate_tz has moved to email.utils

```
>>> import email.utils   # this works on Python2.5 and up
>>> email.utils.parsedate_tz('Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00 -0500')
(1997, 3, 9, 13, 45, 0, 0, 1, -1, -18000)
```

Comment: I thought rf822 was deprecated?

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. There is no deprecation warning even in 2.6 :(

Comment: The above technique does not return `datetime`, rather a `tuple`. The complete code is `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( email.utils.mktime_tz(email.utils.parsedate_tz( rfcdate )), pytz.utc )`. Ref: http://parand.com/say/index.php/2008/02/11/parsing-and-normalizing-dates-with-timezones-in-python/

Comment: Continuation on @AppleGrew comment: Or by using rfc822 module `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(rfc822.mktime_tz(rfc822.parsedate_tz(rfc822String)))`

Comment: In python 3, try email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime.

Comment: Email utils appears to be RFC2822. is that the same as 822?

Comment: @ThomasAhle, the `rfc822` module predated RFC2822. Turns out it's not a great idea to name the module after the RFC :) This was fixed in Python3. The current one is actually RFC5322

Comment: The `rfc822` module was deprecated already in Python 2.3; the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/rfc822.html) points you to [`email`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) package instead, which was introduced in Python 2.2.

Comment: You can simplify slightly; there's an `utcfromtimestamp` method for dates in UTC: `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(email.utils.parsedate_tz(rfcdate)))`

Answer (score 8):

As of python 3.3 there is [email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime(date)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime)

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
>>> datestr = 'Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00 -0500'
>>> parsedate_to_datetime(datestr)
datetime.datetime(1997, 3, 9, 13, 45, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you strip off the time zone, you can do it like this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('Sun, 09 Mar 1997 13:45:00', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have timezones

Comment: He specifically asked how to do it for rfc822 date/time. Since rfc822 includes the timezone, you're answer doesn't solve it. Even worse, it actually returns a different time, depending on the timezone the code was run in, and the timezone the string was generated in (which in web-applications may vary greatly).